# highlight menu on scrolling (if reach div)

Tags: jquery, html, css, menu, navbar

i want highlight the menu point if the div is scrolled // or clicked.

http://jsfiddle.net/WeboGraph/vu6hN/2/ (thats an example what i want)

my code: 
(JS)

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('nav a').on('click', function(event) {
          $(this).parent().find('a').removeClass('active_underlined');
          $(this).addClass('active_underlined');
      });

      $(window).on('scroll', function() {
          $('.target').each(function() {
              if($(window).scrollTop() >= $(this).position().top) {
                  var id = $(this).attr('id');
                  $('nav a').removeClass('active_underlined');
                  $('nav a[href=#'+ id +']').addClass('active_underlined');
              }
          });
      });
    });
```

my (html nav)

```
        <nav>
           <div id="cssmenu">
              <ul id="horizontalmenu" class="underlinemenu">
                  <li><a data-scroll href="#fdesigns"  class="active_underlined">FDesigns</a> </li>
                  <li><a data-scroll href="#skills">skills</a> </li>
                  <li><a data-scroll href="#workflow">WORKFLOW</a> </li>
                  <li><a data-scroll href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a> </li>
                  <li><a data-scroll href="#about">About</a> </li>
                  <li><a data-scroll href="#kontakt">Kontakt</a> </li>
              </ul>   
          </div>
        </nav>
```

my (css)

```
.active_underlined a {
  color: #fff;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ebebeb;
}

a.active_underlined {
  color: #fff;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ebebeb;
}
```

here a link to the project: http://www.f-designs.de/test_onesite

Comment: that fiddle seems to work fine. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: http://www.f-designs.de/test_onesite this is my site and it dont work with the code above

the fiddle is an example what i want on my page

Comment: `position()` method on your `.target` items returns position of (0,0). That implies the `if($(window).scrollTop() >= $(this).position().top) {` is always true.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use `$(this).offset().top` instead of `$(this).position().top`

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vu6hN/28/)

As `.position()` get the current coordinates of the first element in the set of matched elements, relative to the offset parent whereas `.offset()` get the current coordinates of the first element in the set of matched elements, relative to the document.

In your website all the DIV with class inside `.target` are inside  therefore all the element of class `.target` are returning the value `.position().top` equal to 0.

Decrease the offset value so that the `class` change when element reach the menu by making the `if` condition like this:

```
if($(window).scrollTop() >= $(this).offset().top - $("#cssmenu").height())
```

Comment: hey thx it works, but now if i click the menu the element before the clicked element is highlighted (maybe i must set that .offset top calculates some pixels before the top of the browser?)

can u help me please?

Comment: Update the answer. You just have to decrease `cssmenu` height from offset. BTW your site looks amazing.

Comment: @ gaurav kalyan, thanks if u like my site :)

can u give me a more detailed answer // explanation what i have to do? thx and mery x-mas

Comment: I would recommend using @tris timb's answer as well.

Answer (score 3):

Found this in 2018 and ran into a syntax error trying to replicate with a more recent version of jquery (+1.0). In the last line `$('nav a[href=#'+ id +']')` the attribute is not properly escaped and needs to be like so `$('nav a[href="#'+ id +'"]')` (note added "").

Here's where I found this https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/